# Oracle .DBF Files. How to Open and Run Select Statements?

Tags: database, oracle, mount, oracle9i, dbf

We have an Inventory Web Application and an Oracle Database

Oracle Version.. as I see in SQL Plus:

```
Connected to:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

( I am very new to Oracle or SQL Plus)

Our Web Application and Database are working fine in the Production System.. and we are able to connect to the database and run sql statements through ODBC (using Microsoft Access)... to view on any table that we want in the Oracle DB..

However we have an investigation to do... about a record's last update time... and in the production table the last update time is now changed to the latest.. And, we need to access the database in the state it was about 24 hours ago..
**Fortunately, we do have a full database backup 24 hours earlier... as shown in the below screenshot.. with temp01.dbf highlighted (this is where the actual tables and data are).**

The question is this:

How can we mount this database to Oracle or anywhere else (with any other application) to view a particular table `e.g. TBL_USERLIST`.. and run a select query on this table.. to find the last update time of a particular user based on this backup table.. ( I have this information in the production database... but that is now too late for the investigation purposes... and I need to go back in time to find the previous last update time).

How can we do this easily... without going through many hoops... In an ideal situation.. all i want to do is mount the below files (as a copy).. in some application or existing server... and run `"select * from tbl_userlist"` without stopping the Production System or have any down time.

Is this possibly easily? How? Thank you.

[image: Oracle DBF and Other Files from the backup]

Comment: If you have `FLASHBACK` enabled, you can look into it. Other than that I don't think you can use a backup of a datafile in the same or other databases just like that

Comment: Hi.. How to know if FLASHBACK is enabled? Please as i am so new to sql plus or oracle.

Comment: Use this `select name, flashback_on from v$tablespace;`

Comment: This is the error we got.. for the above flashback_on query.... ########ORA-00942: table or view does not exist######### I don't know what it means.. however.. i can go back in time for the table for about 24 hours.. so it means flashback is working... but only that i don't understand the above error.

Comment: Maybe you do not have the privilege to access the view from your current user. Try using sys user. Or grant select privilege to your user.

Comment: Do you have the backup of control file along with your datafile backup?

Comment: I have no idea... what that is.. can you find anything from the screenshot in my question? Is it relevant for the control files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95007/discussion-between-varun-rao-and-ihightower).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have FLASHBACK enabled in the environment, then you can do a simple query like below

```
select *
from TBL_USERLIST
as of TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-11-12 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this.. this is really excellent.. and it worked!!! However.. there is one problem... I can only go back to about 24 hours.. and anything earlier.. it throws an error like this....      ########## ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 9 with name "_SYSSMU9$" too smal l########## and i see that the query works perfectly... However.. now it is too late.. and i need to go back more in time... So the other option is to just use the .dbf file i believe.. (any help on that please... or any other method.).

Comment: The error is because of the FLASHBACK configurations of your environment. Change them so you will not end up in this situation again. And as far as i know you do not take backup of a database by backing up the datafile. (I don't know how that is valid if the database is live.) I'll however check and get back within a few minutes

Comment: @ihightower Nope. I think you can't get the tables or data from a backup datafile. Infact the idea of keeping the datafile backup itself is wrong. Oracle is much complicated. It is not like mysql where you can play around with databases as files. Consider `RMAN` backups and recovery from next time.

Comment: set parameter `db_flashback_retention_target` value in minutes as your requirement for future purposes.

Comment: please see my comments in the question... for the error we got for the flashback_on query which you gave... and for your above comments.. setting the minutes for too long in the past.. does that affect the performance or anything? Thank you so much.. so far the direction has been great.. Much appreciated!